# Bootstrap 5 - No reaction for pile navigation

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I created a simple bootstrap 5 template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.80.0">
    <title>Detailed View</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png"
          sizes="180x180">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32"
          type="image/png">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16"
          type="image/png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg"
          color="#7952b3">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../css/t02-stockDetailView_style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<main class="container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Library</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>


    <div class="text-center py-5 px-3">

        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 px-0">
                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/380x500" alt="" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                                <h4>
                                    Bhaumik Patel</h4>
                                <p>CEO of Apple Inc.</p>
                                <small><cite title="San Francisco, USA">San Francisco, USA <i
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">
                                </i></cite></small>
                                <p>
                                    <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> email@example.com
                                    <br/>
                                    <i class="bi bi-globe"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com"> www.jquery2dotnet.com</a>
                                    <br/>
                                    <i class="bi bi-gift"></i> June 02, 1988</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

        <div class="row mt-3">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">test</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">test2</div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>

</main><!-- /.container -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When pressing the `Home` or `Profile` button nothing gets loaded.

I am loading all js components from bootstrap 5.

Any suggestions why the `out of the box` pile navigation does not work?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i checked bootstrap 5 documentatiton no data-toggle attribute.

Change **data-toggle** with **data-bs-toggle**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.80.0">
    <title>Detailed View</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png"
          sizes="180x180">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32"
          type="image/png">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16"
          type="image/png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg"
          color="#7952b3">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../css/t02-stockDetailView_style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<main class="container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Library</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>


    <div class="text-center py-5 px-3">

        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 px-0">
                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/380x500" alt="" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                                <h4>
                                    Bhaumik Patel</h4>
                                <p>CEO of Apple Inc.</p>
                                <small><cite title="San Francisco, USA">San Francisco, USA <i
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">
                                </i></cite></small>
                                <p>
                                    <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> email@example.com
                                    <br/>
                                    <i class="bi bi-globe"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com"> www.jquery2dotnet.com</a>
                                    <br/>
                                    <i class="bi bi-gift"></i> June 02, 1988</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

        <div class="row mt-3">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">test</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">test2</div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>

</main><!-- /.container -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```